# contentProvider and search by name and not ID Android

Tags: android

it's the first time I'm using the content provider.
so I have this:

```
public class ContactsContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private ContactsDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher =
            new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);    

    private static final int ONE_CONTACT = 1;
    private static final int CONTACTS = 2;
    private static final int CONTACT = 3;
    static {    
        uriMatcher.addURI(ContactsDatabaseDescription.AUTHORITY,
                Contact.TABLE_NAME + "/#", ONE_CONTACT);
        uriMatcher.addURI(ContactsDatabaseDescription.AUTHORITY,
                Contact.TABLE_NAME, CONTACTS);
        uriMatcher.addURI(ContactsDatabaseDescription.AUTHORITY,
                Contact.TABLE_NAME + "/*" , CONTACT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {    
        dbHelper = new ContactsDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }    

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection,
                        String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {    
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(Contact.TABLE_NAME);

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ONE_CONTACT:
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(
                        Contact._ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment());
                break;
            case CONTACTS:
                break;
             default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        getContext().getString(R.string.invalid_query_uri) + uri);
        }    

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);    

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    // insert a new contact in the database
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        Uri newContactUri = null;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case CONTACTS:
                // insert the new contact--success yields new contact's row id
                long rowId = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(
                        Contact.TABLE_NAME, null, values);    

                if (rowId > 0) {
                    newContactUri = Contact.buildContactUri(rowId);


                    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                }
                else
                    throw new SQLException(
                            getContext().getString(R.string.insert_failed) + uri);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        getContext().getString(R.string.invalid_insert_uri) + uri);
        }

        return newContactUri;
    }    

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values,
                      String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int numberOfRowsUpdated; // 1 if update successful; 0 otherwise

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ONE_CONTACT:

                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();    

                numberOfRowsUpdated = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(
                        Contact.TABLE_NAME, values, Contact._ID + "=" + id,
                        selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        getContext().getString(R.string.invalid_update_uri) + uri);
        }

        if (numberOfRowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        return numberOfRowsUpdated;
    }    

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int numberOfRowsDeleted;

        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case ONE_CONTACT:

                String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();    

                numberOfRowsDeleted = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(
                        Contact.TABLE_NAME, Contact._ID + "=" + id, selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                        getContext().getString(R.string.invalid_delete_uri) + uri);
        }    

        if (numberOfRowsDeleted != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        return numberOfRowsDeleted;
    }
}
```

My database is

```
public class ContactsDatabaseDescription {
    public static final String AUTHORITY =
            "com.example.afran.bdcontacts.data";    

    private static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI =
            Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);
        public static final class Contact implements BaseColumns {
            public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts"; // table's name
            public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                    BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(TABLE_NAME).build();

            public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
            public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "lastName";
            public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
            public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";

        public static Uri buildContactUri(long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
        }
    }
}
```

and on this fragment I read one last name (search) and I want to find the contact and I do not know how

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {    

    public interface DetailFragmentListener {
        void onContactDeleted();  
        void onEditContact(Uri contactUri);
    }

    private static final int CONTACT_LOADER = 0;  

    private DetailFragmentListener listener;  
    private Uri contactUri;  

    private TextView prenomTextView;
    private TextView nomTextView;
    private TextView emailTextView;  
    private TextView typeTextView;      

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        listener = (DetailFragmentListener) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);      

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (arguments != null)
            contactUri = arguments.getParcelable(MainActivity.CONTACT_URI);    

        View view =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);    

        prenomTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstNameTextView);
        nomTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastNameTextView);
        emailTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        typeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.typeTextView);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER, null, this);
        return view;
    }    

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                listener.onEditContact(contactUri);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                deleteContact();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_search:    
               searchContact();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void searchContact() {
        final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.menuitem_recherche);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.label_lastName);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString();

                return;
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return;
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();    
    }

    private void deleteContact() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirm_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirm_message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface dialog, int button) {    

                    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                            contactUri, null, null);
                    listener.onContactDeleted();  
                }
            }
        );
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
        builder.create().show();  
      }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        CursorLoader cursorLoader;

        switch (id) {
            case CONTACT_LOADER:
                cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                        contactUri,  
                        null,  
                        null,  
                        null,  
                        null);  
                break;
            default:
                cursorLoader = null;
                break;
        }

        return cursorLoader;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        if (data != null && data.moveToFirst()) {

            int firstIndex = data.getColumnIndex(ContactsDatabaseDescription.Contact.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME);
            int lastIndex = data.getColumnIndex(ContactsDatabaseDescription.Contact.COLUMN_LAST_NAME);
            int emailIndex = data.getColumnIndex(ContactsDatabaseDescription.Contact.COLUMN_EMAIL);
            int typeIndex = data.getColumnIndex(ContactsDatabaseDescription.Contact.COLUMN_TYPE);

            prenomTextView.setText(data.getString(firstIndex));
            nomTextView.setText(data.getString(lastIndex));
            emailTextView.setText(data.getString(emailIndex));
            typeTextView.setText(data.getString(typeIndex));    
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to search for a match of any column in your table. You simply need the contentUri, and where and whereArgs parameters for the query. Ensure your Uri points to the whole table. Assuming you want to match columns called "first_name" and "surname" with Strings called firstName and surname.

```
String where = "first_name =? and surname =?";
String[] whereArgs = {firstName, surname};
```

You can use parentheses and "and" and "or" to construct more complex queries. With numerical fields you can use > and < etc. You must ensure whereArgs has as many elements as where has "?"